# Docker Compose In Production

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

Trying to use docker-compose to build and up a simple Node.js application. Although I ran into the same problem with a Django application so I think I'm just missing some sort of vital step. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.2.1
CMD mkdir -p /var/app
COPY . /var/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node /var/app/index.js
```

When I run docker compose up pointed towards a digital ocean machine it throws a node error suggesting it can't find the code in /var/app. Is there some other mechanism I am supposed to use to get my code onto the machine other than docker?

Comment: You should have only one `CMD` in your docker file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line `CMD mkdir -p /var/app` is wrong. It should be only one `CMD` in a Dockerfile, usually at the end.

Only the last `CMD` directive in a chain of inherited docker images will be executed.

You should use `RUN` instead

From [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#cmd)

> There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.
>
> The main purpose of a CMD is to provide defaults for an executing container.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the mkdir step. You also need to set the working directory.